# How to log in as a root from TightVNC

Tags: 14.04, vnc, tightvncserver

I followed *[How To Install Apache Tomcat on Ubuntu 12.04](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/articles/how-to-install-apache-tomcat-on-ubuntu-12-04)* and installed VNC Server on my remote machine, but now when I log in through [TightVNC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TightVNC) it logs in as a VNC user. How do I instead log in as root?

Note: I am using Ubuntu 14.04 (Trusty Tahr).

Answer (score 2):

- Of course, do this only in a private intranet web server because running local session as root is bad, and running a vnc distant root session is worst.
- Verify if you can open a local session as root using the login  screen: as this is normally disabled in Ubuntu, you may need to  enable root local session running `sudo passwd root` and double type a  password (it will be local root password).  Then recheck opening session as root.
- Then, for vnc, one solution is to add this line:
  `/usr/bin/vncserver`
  editing the `/etc/rc.local` file . The commands from this file are executed at boot and as root.  So it will start a vncserver session at next boot.
  *May be you will need to remove the -e  at the end of the first line in /etc/rc.local

  to get:

  `#!/bin/sh`*
- Then run
  `sudo vncpassword`   and double type  a password (will be for clients vnc access)  .
- reboot
- From your client vncviewer, you will access  the "root" vnc session using  `ip_server:1`   or  `ip_server:2` as "host" . If it is ok, you will be prompt for the vnc password and see root desktop.
- If problems: try to run as root in a local server terminal  `killall Xvnc4` then `/usr/bin/vncserver` and see messages.

Comment: I do not have any such file "/usr/bin/vncserver"  in my case this file here "/etc/init.d/vncserver" i have to add this path?

Comment: /etc/init.d/vncserver is the service script, type `which vncserver` to see where is the executable

Comment: It is showing same as u defined after in the /etc/rc.local file . what you written i did not get you can u explain it

Comment: edit /etc/rc.local as root `sudo gedit /etc/rc.local` to add ` /usr/bin/vncserver` at the end : next time you boot it should run automatically  vncserver as root

Comment: So i have to reboot the machine?Bue even after reboot its start with vnc user not root user

Comment: yes , commands in /etc/rc.local are executed at boot time

Comment: I just reboot the machine no effect again i login from TightVNCviewer as a "vnc" user not as a root user

Comment: i edited the answer .